# Show Category hierarchy using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I wanna show a category hierarchy data and I use angularJS with ng-repeat and ng-if.Here's to my demo file:

```
  <div ng-app="" ng-controller="DanhMucController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList" ng-if="danhmuc.depended==0">{{danhmuc.name}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList" ng-if="danhmuc.depended==2">
            {{danhmuc.name}}
            <ul ng-repeat="danhmuc in DanhMucList" ng-if="danhmuc.depended==4">
              <li>{{danhmuc.name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

controller:

```
<script>
    function DanhMucController($scope, $http) {
        var url = "category.txt";
        $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
            $scope.DanhMucList = response;
        });
    }
</script>
```

this file category data :

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Parent1",
  "depended": "0"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Parent2",
  "depended": "0"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Parent3",
  "depended": "0"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "ChildA",
  "depended": "1"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "name": "ChildB",
  "depended": "2"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "name": "ChildC",
  "depended": "3"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "name": "grandChildA",
  "depended": "4"
}, {
  "id": "8",
  "name": "grandChildB",
  "depended": "5"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "name": "grandChildC",
  "depended": "6"
}, {
  "id": "10",
  "name": "grandChildD",
  "depended": "5"
}, {
  "id": "11",
  "name": "grandChildE",
  "depended": "6"
}, {
  "id": "12",
  "name": "grandChildF",
  "depended": "3"
}]
```

[category Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoVYZ.png)

But I can not define the id of parent so it dont show data which I need .It must display:

-Parent 1 contain ChildA.

-Parent 2 contain ChildB.

-Parent 3 contain ChildC.

Everyone can suggest me a solution for my issues. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/FSgHFURt1aNvnk5Nqv8n/).

I would suggest though you arrange your data better instead of looping over the same data 3 times.

Comment: I am sorry about this inconvenient. I just arranged my data better. Can you help me to give me a suggestions?

Comment: sorry for the late response.
I would do something like [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/FSgHFURt1aNvnk5Nqv8n/).
Please see the hierarchy of the data and the loops, you are going only over the children of an object if they exist and not over all the data each time.

Comment: yup.. that's right. You're a great man :D . by the way, Can you please give me a more specific explanarion about how this code works withoud ng-if="a.children.length > 0"? code here: [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/nLZ56CTSml41jOIgQvaM/)
and do I have problem if I build many element category based on category hierarchy?

Comment: right, the ng-if is redundant in this case because if there are no children then ng-repeat won't go over anything.
I'm not sure i got your second question but this hierarchy is better than what you had before

Comment: this case is demo for my project. after I will use sql server to manage my database,because I will use category hierarchy without children ( this is my data file) .... and if I use your category hierarchy, how would I build my data category? It's difficult?

Comment: i don't know what your data should look like in the future, but for the scenario you mentioned here this hierarchy is better. For different scenarios maybe your data should be built differently.

Comment: hmm.. okay..Thank you very much, I will be build my database like your structure because it's easy to rendering and easy to manage my data!